# How can I fill in a column missing 20% in the dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

There is a column missing 54% in the dataset. 17031 data is missing in this column. I did not delete it because this column is important to me. I filled it with knn. But because its neighbors are also nan values, some rows are still filled in nan. I changed the number of neighbors 3, I tried 4 and 5 but the result is the same. 12116 lines remain nan. Do you suggest me to wipe the column, do you have any other recommended method?

```
from sklearn.impute import KNNImputer
df_n = df[["Credit_Score","Annual_Income"]]
var_names = df_n.columns
n_df = np.array(df_n)

imputer = KNNImputer(n_neighbors=3)
new_data = imputer.fit_transform(n_df)
df2=pd.DataFrame(new_data, columns=var_names)
for s in ["Credit_Score","Annual_Income"]:
    df[[s]] = df2[s]
```

Comment: Maybe fill it with the mean value? The answer really depends on what you are going to do with this column next.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sklearn's SimpleImputer ([link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html)), which can fill the missing values with the mean, median, or other constant related to the column. This is a simpler imputation strategy than KNN, but it does ensure that no nans are remaining after imputation.